# How to do a POST request with Spring Security and RESTful?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, restful-authentication

I'm learning about Spring Rest and I have a Restful controller with GET, PUT, POST and DELETE requests. After that I added Spring Security with 2 roles user and admin. And I don't understand why I can do only GET requests, if I try to do a POST, PUT or DELETE request I receive 403 Forbidden.

Rest Controller:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @GetMapping("/task")
    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return taskRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/task")
    public void addTask(@RequestBody Task task) {
        System.out.println("Here 111"); 
        taskRepository.save(task);
    }

    @PutMapping("/task/{id}")
    public void editTask(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody Task task) {
        Task existingTask = taskRepository.findById(id).get();
        Assert.notNull(existingTask, "Task not found");
        existingTask.setDescription(task.getDescription());
        taskRepository.save(existingTask);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/task/{id}")
    public void deleteTask(@PathVariable long id) {
        Task taskToDel = taskRepository.findById(id).get();
        taskRepository.delete(taskToDel);
    }
}
```

Spring Security Configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("ady")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("12345"))
                .roles("USER")
                .and()
            .withUser("gigel")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("abcde"))
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/task").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/movie").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

The problem was due to CSRF protection. I disabled CSRF and it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Funny thing,

I think you got `403` because you have entered the wrong password, check it out here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

it should be

```
   auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("ady")
            .password("12345")
            .roles("USER")
            .and()
        .withUser("gigel")
            .password("abcde")
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
```